# Progress Plugin Invalid Options in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr2aI.png)

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

```
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
    options should match exactly one schema in oneOf
```

Comment: Nothing new about this?

Comment: I get same error.